# Google vision api をローカルではなくウェブ上の画像で使用したい

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-storage

やりたい事はタイトル通りgoogle vision apiでウェブ上にある画像のocrなどを行いたいと思ってます。
画像パス=test.jpg
などのローカルデータは読み込めるんですが、
画像パス=https://example.com/test.jpg
とかにするとエラーになります。
Gcs上に置いてある画像で使用したいと思ってます。
使用してるコードはpython3でgae、flask環境です。
サンプルコードなどがありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

I want to do ocr of images on the web with google vision api as the title. Image path = test.jpg You can read local data such as Image path = `https://example.com/test.jpg` If you do, an error will occur. I'd like to use it with the images on Gcs. The code I am using is python3 with gae and flame environment. Please let me know if you have sample code.

```
#imgの読み込み
img_url_0 = 'test.jpg'#ローカル画像
img_url = 'https://example.com/test.jpg'#gcs上の画像

with open(img_url, 'rb') as f_img:#ここでエラー
    img_byte = f_img.read()
    img_base64 = base64.b64encode(img_byte)

result = request_cloud_vison_api(img_base64)
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは「自己回答」も歓迎ですので、せっかく質問を投稿したのであれば解決した質問も削除ではなく「回答」を投稿して知識を共有してもらうと他のユーザーの助けになると思います。

Comment: 自己解決したからといって質問を消すというのは、「質問を読んで考えた人」「回答しようとした人」「質問を推敲した人」にとても不誠実だと感じます。

Comment: このサイトを参照している方のために、この場合どういうエラーがでて、コードをどのように変更して対応したか書いて下さると有難く思います。

Comment: 今回は回答して頂いてるので敬意を評して残すと明記してあります。使い方は人それぞれですがなんかしらメリットがあればコードも明記します。(今回の例は回答頂いた内容から容易に推測できるものかなとも思いますが、、)

Comment: キータもそうなんだけど、この手のサイトって地主だけが得をして、実際に手を動かしてる人達にとって金銭的なメリットがないのが残念です。質問した人も回答した人も含めてボランティアで地主に貢献してる構造。なのでこれ以上記載するモチベが働かないのでこれで終わりにします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。@cubick 様のご回答通りということで理解しました。今回はFileSystemとHTTPの取り扱いで勘違いなされたことが原因かと思います。このような勘違いをお持ちになった方が、Google検索などでHITする事例かと思いますので残しておくことは有意義と思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決した場合は、自己回答が推奨されています。毎回消すのはいかがなものかと、というコメントでした。

Answer (score 1):

`open`を使用する場合には、対象のリモートファイルを一旦ローカルに保存する必要があると思います。

もしくは、代わりに [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls) を使用すればリモートファイルを直接開くことが可能なようです。

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://example.com/test.jpg') as response:
   img = response.read()
```

Comment: 読み取る際の記述がpythonだと違うみたいですね。一応解決してましたが、投稿して頂きありがとうございます。

Comment: 比較対象が何か分かりませんが、組み込みの`open`関数が扱えるのはローカルファイルだけなケースが大半かと思います。